# How would you model CoreData to hold an array of custom objects in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

I have two Core Data entities called `PreviousWorkout`, and `ExerciseData`. The `PreviousWorkout` entity holds the following attributes: `date`, `workoutName`, and `exercises`. `exercises` is supposed to be an array of `ExerciseData`. After making the class with Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass, I then did the same thing with the `ExerciseData` entity.

I'm unsure whether or not this is the correct way of storing data using Core Data. My goal is to have a `PreviousWorkout` which contains an array of `ExerciseData` as well as `date` and `workoutName`.

The way I'm creating it in code is by creating a `managedbjectContext` with:

```
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
```

Then I create a `PreviousWorkout` array with:

```
let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("PreviousWorkout", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!) as PreviousWorkout
```

I add all my stuff (`date` and `workoutName`) to `newItem`, then I attempt to create an array of ExerciseData with:

```
var exerciseData = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("ExerciseData", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!) as [ExerciseData]
```

The program crashes at this point. I realize that this last line is very wrong but I'm not sure how to create an array of `ExerciseData`. After creating the array I would like to append to it, and then set values for its attributes before setting the `newItem.exercises` equal to the `ExerciseData` object.

Is this the correct way of creating a Core Data object that contains an array? How do I create the array of `[ExerciseData]`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An entity is essentially a table so you would store many Workouts in it and create a Workout entity, not just a PreviousWorkout entity. Then you should have an Exercise entity and store many exercises in it. Then to store an "array" in Core Data, you make a relationship between the two entities (probably a many to many relationship because each workout can have many exercises and each exercise can be a part of many workouts). Then to add exercises to a workout object, you just append them to a Workout objects `exercises` property which is an `NSSet` and it points at Exercise objects.

So now you have many workout objects and exercise objects, you can fetch the previous workout by using a fetch request and sorting all of your workouts by date or whichever property you want to sort by and taking the first result of the fetch request.

You create a new exercise like so:

```
let exerciseData = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Exercise", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!) as Exercise
```

Comment: thanks! Is my method of creating a new workout (newItem) correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but I would advise renaming "PreviousWorkout" to "Workout"

Comment: alright I will do that. One last thing, you mentioned that the `exercises` property is an NSSet. How do I go about setting that up? It is currently set as `Transformable` in the data model

Comment: It isn't supposed to be of any type. You have to set up a relationship in your data model. Then, when you regenerate you NSManagedObject subclasses, you will see the relationship property of type NSSet